# Keyboard and Mouse input issuess after upgrading to 16.10

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, 16.10, do-release-upgrade

Today I upgraded from a Ubuntu 16.04.2 to Ubuntu 16.10 and after the upgrade is completed and the system is rebooted, Ubuntu just freezes in the LightDM login screen. I doesn't takes any input from the keyboard and touchpad or usb keyboard and usb mouse. I tried my dedicated power button to restart my laptop but it also didn't worked. I didn't have had any problem with Ubuntu before as my Dell laptop came with a Ubuntu pre-installed and my hardware support for Ubuntu is great. Also with this upgrade I noticed that this upgrade didn't tried to install the 16.10 kernel. I have already removed 16.04.2's 4.8 kernel in favor of Xanmod's custom 4.10 kernel and usually upgrades would install the new kernel but this it didn't. Please tell me a way to fix this issue without reinstalling Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can only be solved in the LiveCD. After booting to LiveCD, then chroot into the Ubuntu installation by [following these steps here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery). You will also need to use the OpenDNS nameservers as the default nameserver can't be asscessed via chroot.

Then follow these steps:

```
apt full-upgrade -y
apt install -y ubuntu-desktop
```

This will fix the X-Server stack. Reboot and you will have a working desktop

Comment: didnt work. just says newest version installed