# edit resolv.conf

Tags: upgrade, live-cd, chroot, input

I can't edit /etc/resolv.conf, error: permission denied
I upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 and keyboard & mouse stopped working, following ubuntu KB asks to mount chroot, chroot mounted but dns not working, and can't edit resolv.conf
Please help how to solve network connectivity when booted from a live cd and mounted to chroot.

Comment: I answered the question you asked.  However it isn't clear what this has to do with a LiveCD boot, chroot, network connectivity and so on.  If you are having network and/or kybd/mouse issues on a machine where Ubuntu is installed, you should ask questions about those instead.  The protocol here is one question for each issue.

Comment: You DON'T edit /etc/resolv.conf... it says so right in the file... and, resolv.conf would have NOTHING to do with your keyboard/mouse problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why there are resolvconf.service and systemd-resolved.service services present in ubuntu at the same time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985336/why-there-are-resolvconf-service-and-systemd-resolved-service-services-present-i)

Answer (score 1):

/etc/resolv.conf lists the name servers to query when doing a DNS lookup.  It requires sudo privileges to edit.

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

nano is a simple text editor.

The resolver has nothing to do with keyboard and mouse function.

Comment: this is the situation
https://askubuntu.com/questions/899599/keyboard-and-mouse-input-issuess-after-upgrading-to-16-10

Comment: @Uttam Baroi Right.  As I said, I answered the title question that you asked.  For additional problems, additional questions for each issue should be created.

Answer (score 0):

No edit because it is a symbolic link.
Default resolv.conf:

- /run/systemd/resolve/stub.resolv.conf
- /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

Delete symbolic link, and create a new one.
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

Sample content: nano /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver ::1
nemaserver 127.0.0.1
options edns0
```